# css editor in html,js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, editor

I want to implement option for end users to enable them to change (css)style on page.
For example when they are on styling page, they can click on **header** and popup will appear and in it friendly user interface to select background color, color of the text, borders, padding... just by clicking.

Is something like this available, in from of jquery plugin or...

Comment: Click on a link, or element, with the *text* of `header`, or on the `<header>` element itself?

Comment: it doesn't matter, i can bind function onClick on element I want,
that plugin need just to provide UI for selecting colors, padding...
and then return css class

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://usejquery.com/posts/brosho-design-in-the-browser-jquery-plugin

Comment: Wow, that's a really cool plugin. I'm not sure if it's really usable by end-users in its current state but I guess it wouldn't be too much of a stretch to modify it to use color pickers and, say, drop-down lists for font families, sizes, etc... In fact, I think I might try to do just that (need this functionality on a site I'm working on with customisable user profile pages).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in some code:
Demo: https://cdpn.io/harshavardhana-holla-gmail-com/debug/yLVLYeQ/RBrOJRNNRooM

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
       <style> textarea, iframe
       {
border:2px solid #400040;
height:600px;
width:100%;
}
</style>
     </head>
     <body><table border="2" width="100%" height="100%"> <tr bgcolor="#efdfff"><th>
     <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
<td width="50%" scope="col">  </td> 
<td width="50%" scope="col" align="left"> 
   <center><input onclick="runCode();" type="button" value= "Run Code!"></center>
</td>
</tr>
<td>
<form>
<center><b>Paste Your Code here!</b></center>
<textarea name="sourceCode" id="sourceCode">
<html>
<head> <title>My Codes</title> </head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome Coders!</h1>
<p> Write HTML, Javascript or CSS here & click run code!</p>
</body> 
</html>
</textarea>
</form>
</td>

<td><b><center>Output</b></center>
<iframe name="targetCode"  id="targetCode"> </iframe> </td>
</table>
<script>
function runCode() {
var content = document.getElementById('sourceCode').value;
var iframe = document.getElementById('targetCode');
iframe = (iframe.contentWindow)?iframe.contentWindow:(iframe.contentDocument)? iframe.contentDocument.document: 
iframe.contentDocument;

iframe.document.open();
iframe.document.write(content);
iframe.document.close();
return false;
}
runCode();
</script>
</tr>
</th>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I created some iframes which shows the results!